# pygame dragging a background image

Tags: pygame

This is a follow up question to the code below.
I commented out the y imgPos so the image can only be dragged left or right.  But you can drag the image forever in either direction.  How can you put a stopping point so you can not drag it any further left and right.

I have tried imgPos.clamp_ip(screen)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
img = pygame.image.load('sky.png')

imgPos = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (0, 0))

LeftButton = 0
while 1:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT: exit(0)
        if e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
                # clicked and moving
                rel = e.rel
                imgPos.x += rel[0]
                #imgPos.y += rel[1]
    screen.fill(0)
    screen.blit(img, imgPos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this

```
if e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
    if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
        # clicked and moving
        rel = e.rel
        imgPos.x += rel[0]
        if imgPos.x < MIN_X:
            imgPos.x = MIN_X
        elif imgPos.x > MAX_X:
            imgPos.x = MAX_X
```

If you want to make this a little neater, you could wrap it up in a `pygame.Rect` object, which would also make it easier to add the same functionality to the `imgPos.y`

```
border = pygame.Rect(MIN_X, MIN_Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

if e.type == MOUSEMOTION:
    if e.buttons[LeftButton]:
        # clicked and moving
        rel = e.rel
        imgPos.x += rel[0]
        if imgPos.left < border.left:
            imgPos.left = border.left 
        elif imgPos.right > border.right:
            imgPos.right = border.right
```